# Boolean indexing for collection of Data objects

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I have a collection of `torch_geometric.data.Data` objects on GPU, and I want to select a subset of them using boolean indexing rather than a `for` loop. The ideas I had were:

- Get boolean indexing on the dataloader itself (i.e. `dataloader[x > 0]`)
- Get a Tensor of `Data` objects (which i can't seem to do due to datatype restrictions).
- Move a `numpy` array of `Data` objects to GPU (Not sure if possible).

If anyone can help me do one of the above or has another method for boolean indexing, I would truly appreciate it.

Comment: Boolean indexing would only be supported by numpy in this case (PyTorch can only have numerical types within Tensor). It would be pretty inefficient if your data is on GPU (copying it back to CPU), hence I’d stick with for loop/list comprehension.